# How can I change the permissions on a usb flash drive?

Tags: permissions, chmod, sd-card

My sd card in my usb card reader will not allow me to add files while in ext4. I checked permissions and it's in root. I'm hoping if I change the permissions to non-root, it will let me add files.

`sudo chmod 777 filename` = I don't know the file name; I put in the random numbers/ letters assigned to it, but get error: `no such file or directory`. Same with `chown`.

When I put the usb card-reader into the computer, the comp automatically gives the ext media a name, such as `lj4l5jlj069ofjrkle5kg05`.

```
in a terminal:
whoami@server:/media/whoami/t9gjkg-tji-gjgj-gogjf-gjgu-i94k4-k5k 

$ sudo chmod 777 t9gjkg-tji-gjgj-gogjf-gjgu-i94k4-k5k

"no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your working directory is `/media/whoami/t9gjkg-tji-gjgj-gogjf-gjgu-i94k4-k5k`, then directory `t9gjkg-tji-gjgj-gogjf-gjgu-i94k4-k5k` is not found, because you're already in it. You can then use

```
sudo chmod 777 .
```

to change the permissions.

Or simply use the absolute path to execute the command. This way is independent of the working directory:

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/whoami/t9gjkg-tji-gjgj-gogjf-gjgu-i94k4-k5k
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy - that did the trick!! Been wondering for a few years why I could not put any files onto a flash drive formatted to ext4. Another post stated to check permissions. I used the "sudo chmod 777 (space)." The same for "chown". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone - in my case the problem wasn't permissions to read the path to the device itself, but to the /media/[user] directory. Probably some problem caused by multiple dist-upgrades (the initial installation was very old).
So if you put in

```
ls /media/[user]
```

and [tab] doesn't show you the device directory, that's probably the issue. Just try:

```
sudo chown [user] /media/[user]
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! This also caused my Windows partitions to be inaccessible (without sudo). Clicking on them in Nautilus auto-mounts them under /media/[user] and then caused an error message with missing permissions. I don't know either what caused this but getting ownership back fixed it.